# Azure CDN - With Local Web Server

Tags: azure, cdn, varnish

Hello I'm looking at a method for speeding up a website and providing a 5MB download (Windows App + Later this year Android version) to international customers. The numbers etc are not known at this stage but would like to know what options are available. The web server is based in NZ currently and is a WordPress install.

I'm new to these subject areas, so not 100% sure on the best move. So have a few Questions?

Would a Proxy such as Varnish be enough for a few 100 downloads a day (Possibly Hopeful)? - if hosted in NZ - its likely to be slow for international customers - without testing would be hard to know - have had a Google and haven't found anything to answer this thoroughly yet.

Could I use Azure CDN and point that at my current web server - if so where would I find good documentation on this? Or could someone provide some measure of cost here, the CDN pricing refers to the locations - I assume that would refer to each edge server - so perhaps would need to purchase a few locations to get a thorough coverage? 
I assume once its setup it isn't too much hassle to add in more locations if needed + I think if we had an Australian location (Perhaps first location) - it should in theory be quite a bit faster than from NZ (Not that Azure offers)

Will keep looking in the meantime...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Azure CDN](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cdn/) would be a good solution.  However, you don't "point" Azure CDN at your server. You upload and manage content in [Azure BLOB Storage](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/) and enable CDN capabilities that basically duplicates your content to all Azure data centers and uses the CDN capability to pull from the location closest to the client.  The CDN provides a CDN based URL or custom URL to link your content in a website.

Comment: Thanks that helps alot, so I add the download to Blog, and load the CDN against the content. Is it possible to add web servers to GEO locations using Azure? So that Americans would get content from an American server, etc against the same domain mydomain.com

Comment: You don't "add" servers to CDNs - that is the job of the CDN - to position your content at locations around the world, automatically, without you having to do anything - read the Azure CDN Overview - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-overview/